# How to keep the two digits after the decimal point

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

If I use `NumberForm`,it is a very nice answer

```
SeedRandom[1]
result1 = NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 2}] & /@ RandomReal[20, 20]
```

> `{16.35,2.23,15.79,3.76,4.83,1.31,10.84,4.62,7.92,14.01,4.24,14.97,8.46,4.95,19.54,16.50,18.51,11.56,5.86,4.16}`

Just one defect,it is not can do any calculation with it anymore.Such as we cannot expect `result1+2` will run normally.So I use `Export` and `Import` to process it like

```
result=Import[Export["tem.txt", result1, "List"], "List"]
```

> `{16.35,2.23,15.79,3.76,4.83,1.31,10.84,4.62,7.92,14.01,4.24,14.97,8.46,4.95,19.54,16.50,18.51,11.56,5.86,4.16}`

The `result` is exactly what I want.But is there any elegant method can do this?

Comment: The two methods are contradictory in that they do completely different things. So it remains unclear what you actually want. Apparently, you're expecting to have *all* numerical output rounded (as in the second example). That would lead to all sorts of trouble in reusing the results, so it appears to be a very bad idea.

Comment: Maybe you want this: `NumberForm[result1=RandomReal[20,20],{Infinity,2}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$PrePrint = NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 2}] &;
```

Comment: Good lesson for usage of `Infinity`.But actually we have not get those numbers what I want,just show it?I mean,you have not get a `result1` with two digits after the decimal point,just show it in that form.

Comment: You mean you're trying to mimic the behavior of…  Er… rounding calculation by hand?

Comment: Yep,something like that..

Comment: And I have include your usage of `Infinity` to my post.Hope do not mind that.

Comment: Well, then I should say I doubt if simply controling the digit of number will work. As far as I can tell, many posts tagged with [precision] and [accuracy] have suggested that, the… Er … rounding rule of _Mathematica_ and manual calculation have subtle difference, though their behaviors are similar. BTW, do you know there's no one-to-one correspondence between decimals and floating number? (See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html )